# How to copy an entire array (not element by element)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, copy

Please refer to the code (and comments) below. 
I am trying to make array = newArray. 
 What is the correct syntax to do this in C++?
 I am trying to point **array** to the same memory location as **newArray** in **memoryCopy()**,
 thus copying **newArray** into **array**, without having to do it element-by-element as I did in **deepCopy()**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void deepCopy(int array[], int size);
void memoryCopy(int *array, int size);
void show(int array[], int size);

int main ()
{
    int array[] = {1,1,1};
    show(array,3); // shows array [] = {1,1,1}
    deepCopy(array, 3);
    show(array,3); // shows array [] = {0,0,0}
    memoryCopy(array, 3);
    show(array,3); // shows array [] = {5,0,0}
    // I need the above to show {5, 5, 5} ^ ^
    // How can I do this in memoryCopy() using pointers?
}

void memoryCopy(int *array, int size)
{
     int newArray[] = {5,5,5};
     // I need to make array = newArray ...
     // ... but without copying it over element by element
     memcpy(array,newArray, 3); // <--???
}

void deepCopy(int array[], int size)
{
    int newArray [] = {0,0,0};
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array[i] = newArray[i]; 
}

void show(int array[], int size)
{
    int i;
    cout << "array [] = {";
    for (i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
        cout << array[i] << ",";
    cout << array[i] << "}" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::copy()`.

Comment: how? What I need is an example of the syntax to do this.

Comment: Can you check with `memcpy(array,newArray, 3*sizeof(int));`?

Comment: IF you use std::vector or anoter STL container, you could write new=old and it would make a copy.

Comment: @nulldreamer [Here's the reference with examples](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: Thank you ALL!! The solution of Manthan Tilva worked!! memcpy(array,newArray, 3*sizeof(int));

Answer (score 1):

If C++ 11 or newer is available, use `std::array<T,N>` instead of C-Style array.
Example:

```
std::array<int,3> my_array {1,1,1};
auto new_array=my_array; // deep copy
```

Answer (score -2):

Thank you all for the quick responses! 
SO much help so fast, you are awesome!

Below is how it worked

```
void shallowCopy(int *array, int size)
{
    int newArray[] = {5,5,5};
    memcpy(array,newArray, 3*sizeof(int)); // <--WORKS
    // thank you Manthan Tilva!
}
```

Comment: Well, you're copying to a local array, how's that useful?

Comment: Just trying to figure out how to copy array in a function in C++. Was not sure of the syntax. Thank you for your answer!